# debug python 3.7 AWS lambda locally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created a zip file with `main.py` and entrypoint `handler` function for AWS Lambda using the runtime python 3.7.

The zip file was packaged inside a Amazon Linux image on EC2 using 3.7.3 python.

I had some errors running on the AWS lambda, so decided if there's a way to run the function locally.

My main.py is below:

```
import datetime
import logging
import os
import re
import subprocess

import boto3
import certbot.main
import raven

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def list_files(folder_path):
  onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(folder_path) if path.isfile(path.join(folder_path, f))]
  logger.info('## path')
  logger.info(onlyfiles)


def read_and_delete_file(path):
  with open(path, 'r') as file:
    contents = file.read()
  os.remove(path)
  return contents


def provision_cert(email, domains):
  certbot.main.main([
    'certonly',                             # Obtain a cert but don't install it
    '-n',                                   # Run in non-interactive mode
    '--agree-tos',                          # Agree to the terms of service,
    '--email', email,                       # Email
    '--dns-route53',                        # Use dns challenge with route53
    '-d', domains,                          # Domains to provision certs for
    # Override directory paths so script doesn't have to be run as root
    '--config-dir', '/tmp/config-dir/',
    '--work-dir', '/tmp/work-dir/',
    '--logs-dir', '/tmp/logs-dir/',
  ])

  first_domain = domains.split(',')[0]
  first_domain_cert_folder = re.sub('\*\.', '', first_domain)
  path = '/tmp/config-dir/live/' + first_domain_cert_folder + '/'
  logger.info('## path')
  logger.info(path)

  list_files(path)

  return {
    'certificate': read_and_delete_file(path + 'cert.pem'),
    'private_key': read_and_delete_file(path + 'privkey.pem'),
    'certificate_chain': read_and_delete_file(path + 'fullchain.pem')
  }

def should_provision(domains):
  existing_cert = find_existing_cert(domains)
  if existing_cert:
    now = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
    not_after = existing_cert['Certificate']['NotAfter']
    return (not_after - now).days <= 30
  else:
    return True

def find_existing_cert(domains):
  domains = frozenset(domains.split(','))

  client = boto3.client('acm')
  paginator = client.get_paginator('list_certificates')
  iterator = paginator.paginate(PaginationConfig={'MaxItems':1000})

  for page in iterator:
    for cert in page['CertificateSummaryList']:
      cert = client.describe_certificate(CertificateArn=cert['CertificateArn'])
      sans = frozenset(cert['Certificate']['SubjectAlternativeNames'])
      if sans.issubset(domains):
        return cert

  return None

def notify_via_sns(topic_arn, domains, certificate):
  process = subprocess.Popen(['openssl', 'x509', '-noout', '-text'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf8')
  stdout, stderr = process.communicate(certificate)

  client = boto3.client('sns')
  client.publish(TopicArn=topic_arn,
    Subject='Issued new LetsEncrypt certificate',
    Message='Issued new certificates for domains: ' + domains + '\n\n' + stdout,
  )

def upload_cert_to_acm(cert, domains):
  existing_cert = find_existing_cert(domains)
  certificate_arn = existing_cert['Certificate']['CertificateArn'] if existing_cert else None

  client = boto3.client('acm')
  acm_response = client.import_certificate(
    CertificateArn=certificate_arn,
    Certificate=cert['certificate'],
    PrivateKey=cert['private_key'],
    CertificateChain=cert['certificate_chain']
  )

  return None if certificate_arn else acm_response['CertificateArn']

def handler(event, context):
  try:
    domains = os.environ['LETSENCRYPT_DOMAINS']
    if should_provision(domains):
      cert = provision_cert(os.environ['LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL'], domains)
      upload_cert_to_acm(cert, domains)
      notify_via_sns(os.environ['NOTIFICATION_SNS_ARN'], domains, cert['certificate'])
  except:
    client = raven.Client(os.environ['SENTRY_DSN'], transport=raven.transport.http.HTTPTransport)
    client.captureException()
    raise
```

The zip file is about 20mb. I found [resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-debugging-python.html) on AWS about debugging locally, but frankly, I am a bit lost as to how to get started.

I am not very familiar with AWS and Lambda in general though I am fairly comfortable with Python.

I am on a macOS mojave and use visual studio code as my editor. I am okay to create virtualenv on my mac if that helps.

How do I debug my lambda on my local macbook pro?

Answer (score 4):

As you've found, you can use AWS SAM (with Docker) to debug locally.

Below is a step-by-step guide on getting started:

**Prerequisites**

1. Install Docker: https://docs.docker.com/install/
2. Install AWS CLI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html
3. Install AWS SAM CLI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install.html
4. Install pipenv: https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/install/

**Create example project**

*Useful in giving you an understanding of the structure and debugging locally - you can then substitute the example code for your own.*

`sam init --runtime python3.7`

**Add dependencies**

```
pipenv shell
pipenv install package-names
```

**Run and debug locally**

```
pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
sam build --manifest requirements.txt
sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction --event event.json
```

**Deploy to AWS Lambda**

Make a new bucket, if needed, in which to store the function code:

`aws s3 mb s3://bucket-name`

Create and run a .sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt && sam build --manifest requirements.txt

sam package \
    --output-template-file packaged.yaml \
    --s3-bucket bucket-name

sam deploy \
    --template-file packaged.yaml \
    --stack-name name-of-lambda-stack \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM \
    --region us-east-1
```

Replacing:

- `bucket-name` with the name of the S3 bucket to store the function code
- `name-of-lambda-stack` with the name of the AWS Lambda Stack to deploy to
- `us-east-1` with another [region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) if desired

Your function is now deployed to AWS Lambda.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed writeup! I am going to give this a shot tomorrow morning :)

Comment: Do i need to create a virtual env? I usually do that for my python projects running on my docker host

Comment: Yep, these instructions use `pipenv` as the virtual environment (though you could probably use `virtualenv`).